# seperate entire rows, or selected columns, which contain blank cells

Tags: excel, formula

I need to figure out how to seperate entire rows, or selected columns, which have blank cells in them. They can be seperated to a new worksheet or to a different area of the same worksheet. The rows which do not contain blank cells should not be included in the final result

Comment: may be use VBA script or filter. But top provide better solution, would you mind posting the sample excel?

Comment: @Bharat This has to be done without using VBA. Not sure how to post the excel file data here. But its just regular data with some blank cells.

Comment: I usually use sort to get blank rows to the bottom then delete them using a particular column to sort by.

Comment: Like @SolarMike mentioned either sort them or apply filter and then choose empty value and then delete them

Comment: @SolarMike cant the rows get extracted into a new area without alternating the original data???

Comment: If you "extract" them then you alter the original data...

Comment: So then i guess the only way to get this done is by filtering, sorting and deleting the rows...

Answer (score 0):

By the comments it sounds as if you want a version of your data in a different location, and without any empty rows? Depending on your version of Excel the `filter` function can help you sort out what rows to show in a different location. You'd have to let it spill, and it's maybe not the best way, but depending on what you want to do it might be enough.

You can read more here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759